# Magento 2 Area is already set in Admin Panel

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade

I can't access Admin panel. It return Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

I checked my **System.log**

```
[2018-06-04 14:49:21] main.CRITICAL: Exception message: Area is already set
Trace: #0 /home/criactiv/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Email/Model/Template/Interceptor.php(284): Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate->setForcedArea('design_email_he...')
#1 /home/criactiv/public_html/vendor/magento/module-theme/Model/Design/Config/Validator.php(117): Magento\Email\Model\Template\Interceptor->setForcedArea('design_email_he...')
#2 /home/criactiv/public_html/vendor/magento/module-theme/Model/Design/Config/Validator.php(68): Magento\Theme\Model\Design\Config\Validator->getTemplateText('design_email_he...', Object(Magento\Theme\Model\Data\Design\Config))
#3 /home/criactiv/public_html/vendor/magento/module-theme/Model/DesignConfigRepository.php(91): Magento\Theme\Model\Design\Config\Validator->validate(Object(Magento\Theme\Model\Data\Design\Config))
```

It returns many errors.

I have my **vendor/magento/module-email/Model/AbstractTemplate.php** well set.

```
/**
     * Store the area associated with a template so that it will be returned by getDesignConfig and getDesignParams
     *
     * @param string $templateId
     * @return $this
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException
     */
    public function setForcedArea($templateId)
    {
        if (!isset($this->area)) {
           $this->area = $this->emailConfig->getTemplateArea($templateId);
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

I don't know what seem to be the problem.

Comment: What is the magento 2 version you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your code you are doing

```
$this->state->setAreaCode($value); // with or without $this
```

If the area is already set this will throw an exception with the message that you provided in your question.

Once an area is set it can not be changed.

Comment: I searched my vendor/magento/module-email/Model/AbstractTemplate.php and I'm not using setAreaCode anywhere.

Comment: That is not the only code that executes during a request.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my **System.log**. It was too big. I removed the file and it started to work.

Comment: This error can not be thrown by the contents of a log file

Comment: You’re right. Ir was a manter of lack of resources on my server.